# Why does calling c_str() on a function that returns a string not work?

Tags: c++, string

I have a function that is returning a string. However, when I call it and do `c_str()` on it to convert it into a `const char*`, it only works when I store it into another string first. If I directly call `c_str()` off of the function, it stores garbage value in the `const char*`.

Why is this happening? Feel like I'm missing something very fundamental here...

```
string str = SomeFunction();
const char* strConverted = str.c_str(); // strConverted stores the value of the string properly
const char* charArray= SomeFunction().c_str(); // charArray stores garbage value

static string SomeFunction()
{
    string str;
    // does some string stuff
    return str;
}
```

Comment: c_str() returns the pointer to the underlying char array. The problem is you're calling it on a temporary. So after the `;` the object gets deleted, and presto: you get garbage.

Comment: Some information on "how" it's not working would help.. Compiler errors? Garbage data?  lots of potential things wrong in just this snippet.

Comment: @Yeraze OP clearly stated it stores a garbage value, so it's definitely not a compiler error.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`SomeFunction().c_str()` gives you a pointer to a temporary(the automatic variable `str` in the body of `SomeFunction`). Unlike with references, the lifetime of temporaries isn't extended in this case and you end up with `charArray` being a dangling pointer explaining the garbage value you see later on when you try to use `charArray`.

On the other hand, when you do

```
string str_copy = SomeFunction();
```

`str_copy` is a copy of the return value of `SomeFunction()`. Calling `c_str()` on it now gives you a pointer to valid data.

Comment: Nowdays `str_copy` is actually just moved ownership, but the point is still valid.

Answer (score 4):

The value object returned by a function is a temporary. The results of `c_str()` are valid only through the lifetime of the temporary. The lifetime of the temporary in most cases is to the end of the full expression, which is often the semicolon.

```
const char *p = SomeFunction();
printf("%s\n", p); // p points to invalid memory here.
```

The workaround is to make sure that you use the result of `c_str()` before the end of the full expression.

```
#include <cstring>

char *strdup(const char *src_str) noexcept {
    char *new_str = new char[std::strlen(src_str) + 1];
    std::strcpy(new_str, src_str);
    return new_str;
}

const char *p = strdup(SomeFunction.c_str());
```

Note that `strdup` is a POSIX function, so if you are a platform that supports POSIX, it's already there.

Answer (score 1):

1. The "`string str`" in method `SomeFunction()` is a local variable in `SomeFunction()`, and only survives inside the scope of `SomeFunction()`;
2. Since the return type of the method `SomeFunction()` is string, not a reference of string, after "`return str;`", `SomeFunction()` will return a copy of the value of `str`, which will be stored as a temporary value in some place of memory, after the call of `SomeFunction()`, the temporary value will be destroyed immediately;
3. "`string str = SomeFunction();`" will store the returned temporary value of `SomeFunction()` to string `str`, actually is a copy of that value and stored to `str`, a new memory block is allocated, and the lifetime of `str` is bigger than the returned temporary value of `SomeFunction()`, after the "`;`" the call of `SomeFunction()` is finished, and the returned temporary value is destroyed immediately, the memory is recycled by system, but the copy of this value is still stored in `str`. That is why "`const char* strConverted = str.c_str();`" can get the right value, actually `c_str()` returned a pointer of the initial element of `str` (the first element memory address of `str` pointed string value), not the returned temporary value of `SomeFunction()`;
4. "`const char* charArray= SomeFunction().c_str();`" is different, "`SomeFunction().c_str()`" will return a pointer of the initial element of the returned temporary value (the first element memory address of returned temporary  string value), but after the call of `SomeFunction()`, the returned temporary value is destroyed, and that memory address is reused by the system, `charArray` can get the value of that memory address, but not the value you expected;

Answer (score -5):

Use strcpy to copy the string to a locally defined array and your code will work fine.

Comment: Either way, `SomeFunction().c_str()` will give you an invalid address. If you try to `strcpy` it, that will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Nope. Did it today.  Worked great.

Comment: Could you provide a small, but complete working example that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: That is different in a significant way. The problem is that `c_str()` is called on the result of a function call. This invalidates the internal `char` pointer that `c_str()` gives you because the `string` object, which is local to the function your calling, has gone out of scope. It also hasn't been copied as it would if you had something like `string a = SomeFunction(); ... a.c_str();`. This doesn't happen in the code linked to because `c_str()` isn't directly called on the result of a function call.

Comment: That is why it works.  That is why I said in my answer to use strcpy to cpy the string to a locally defined array.

Comment: I feel that you didn't make that very clear. An example would *really* go a long way. In fact, I'm still not fully sure if you mean something like `char* str = new char[...length goes here...]; strcpy(str, SomeFunction().c_str());`.

Comment: OP's question was, "Why is this happening" not "What's a workaround".