# GLSL error: illegal non-ASCII character

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

I am writing a vertex shader for openGl. This is my code:

```
#version 150

in vec4 vPosition;
in vec3 vNormal;

out vec3 fN;
out vec3 fE;
out vec3 fL;

uniform mat4 model_matrix;
uniform mat4 view_matrix;
uniform mat4 proj_matrix;

uniform vec4 lightPos;

void main()
{
    vec3 pos = (view_matrix * model_matrix * vPosition).xyz;
    vec3 lightPosInCam = (view_matrix * lightPos).xyz;

    fN = normalize(view_matrix * model_matrix * vec4(vNormal,1.0)).xyz;
    fE = normalize(vec3(0,0,0) - pos);
    fL = normalize(lightPosInCam.xyz - pos);

    gl_Position = proj_matrix*view_matrix*model_matrix*vPosition;
}
```

However, when I run my program, it seems like the error says there is some nonASCII character after my `}`, because in console  prints:

```
#version 150

in vec4 vPosition;
in vec3 vNormal;

out vec3 fN;
out vec3 fE;
out vec3 fL;

uniform mat4 model_matrix;
uniform mat4 view_matrix;
uniform mat4 proj_matrix;

uniform vec4 lightPos;

void main()
{
        vec3 pos = (view_matrix * model_matrix * vPosition).xyz;
        vec3 lightPosInCam = (view_matrix * lightPos).xyz;

        fN = normalize(view_matrix * model_matrix * vec4(vNormal,1.0)).xyz;
        fE = normalize(vec3(0,0,0) - pos);
        fL = normalize(lightPosInCam.xyz - pos);

        gl_Position = proj_matrix*view_matrix*model_matrix*vPosition;
}═════════════════════════
Printed Shader Read Status
vshader_hw5.glsl failed to compile:
ERROR: 0:26: '' : illegal non-ASCII character (0xcd)
ERROR: 0:26: '' : illegal non-ASCII character (0xcd)
ERROR: 0:26: '' : illegal non-ASCII character (0xcd)
ERROR: 0:26: '' : illegal non-ASCII character (0xcd)
ERROR: 0:26: '' : illegal non-ASCII character (0xcd)
ERROR: 0:26: '' : illegal non-ASCII character (0xcd)
```

Comment: For all we know your shader loader is fubar.  Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: maybe show the code that you are using to feed the shader source into GL? Seems like maybe your string is not properly null terminated, or you're passing the incorrect length.

Comment: some unseen unicode character or control code is also an option ...

Comment: I was facing a similar problem since I was trying to get c_str() for std::string returned by a function. The string had my shader code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627413/why-does-calling-c-str-on-a-function-that-returns-a-string-not-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I run my program, it seems like the error says there is some nonASCII character after my }, because in console prints:

This is a typical error encountered when the shader source strings to OpenGL are not properly terminated with a zero byte (NUL) and/or if the the buffer length(s) passed do not match the length of the source string.

Solution: If you're not passing the lengths explicitly (i.e. pass NULL for the lengths parameter) make sure the source strings are properly zero terminated. Otherwise make sure, that the lengths properly match the lengths of the source string buffers.