# Filename c_str() corruption when using directory_iterator

Tags: filesystems, c++17, gcc9

When going over all files in a directory with `directory_iterator` storing the `c_str()` name of a file before using it leads invalid reads (and garbage output).

This seems quite odd to me.

Code examples:

**Working:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main() {
 for (auto const &entry : fs::directory_iterator("./")) {
   std::cout << entry.path().filename().c_str() << '\n';
 }
}
```

> valgrind reports no errors.

**Corrupt output:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main() {
 for (auto const &entry : fs::directory_iterator("./")) {
   auto filename = entry.path().filename().c_str();
   std::cout << filename << '\n';
 }
}
```

> valgrind reports 159 invalid reads (of size 1) -- the exact number depends on how many files are in the directory.

Both these snippets have been compiled with gcc 9.1 using the command:
`g++-9.1 test.cpp -std=c++17`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a dangling pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997228/what-is-a-dangling-pointer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does calling c\_str() on a function that returns a string not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627413/why-does-calling-c-str-on-a-function-that-returns-a-string-not-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lifetime of a temporary object is scoped to the statement it was created in.  Informally speaking, a statement is a line of code that ends at a semicolon.  All temporaries stay live until the end of the entire statement.

[From the C++ spec:](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#4)

> When an implementation introduces a temporary object of a class that has a non-trivial constructor ([class.default.ctor], [class.copy.ctor]), it shall ensure that a constructor is called for the temporary object.
>   Similarly, the destructor shall be called for a temporary with a non-trivial destructor ([class.dtor]).
>   **Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression ([intro.execution]) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.**
>   This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception.
>   The value computations and side effects of destroying a temporary object are associated only with the full-expression, not with any specific subexpression.

Dissecting the working example, we see that `operator<<` executes before destruction of temporaries.

- `entry.path()` = temporary #1
- `.filename()` = temporary #2
- `.c_str()` gets the character pointer out of temporary #2
- `.c_str()` passed into `operator<<` of `std::cout` while all of the above are still live
- Call to `operator<<` taking the `.c_str()` pointer is executed and returns.
- Call to `operator<<` taking `'\n'` is executed and returns.
- All the temporaries are destructed.

Dissecting the broken example, we see a dangling pointer:

- `entry.path()` = temporary #1
- `.filename()` = temporary #2
- `.c_str()` gets the character pointer out of temporary #2 and stored in variable `filename`
- End-of-statement: all temporaries destructed.  Now `filename` points at deleted memory -- it is a dangling pointer.
- Call to `operator<<` is passed a dangling pointer, which it dereferences as if it were a valid string = undefined behavior.

You can pull out a local variable without corruption by removing the `.c_str()`, which makes variable `filename` an object of type [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path).  `std::filesystem::path` owns its memory (similar to `std::string`).

```
for (auto const &entry : fs::directory_iterator("./")) {
    auto filename = entry.path().filename();
    std::cout << filename << '\n';
}
```

[`path` also supports `ostream` output directly](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/operator_ltltgtgt), without the need for `.c_str()`.